# Unable to open Power point using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to concatenate filepath and filename and pass that concatenated string to presentations.open() function.But, it is throwing an error as unable to open ppt.
However, instead of passing concatenated string in open() if I pass the path normally,Im able to open the ppt.

Kindly help me on this.I'm quite new to VBA

Thanks in Advance

Below is my code:

```
    Dim sListFilePath As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim c As String
    Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

    sListFilePath = "filepath"
    Name = "filename.pptx"
    c = Chr(34) & sListFilePath & Name & Chr(34)
    Debug.Print c
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(c)
```

Comment: Could you describe  _it is throwing an error as unable to open ppt_ in detail. What error do you get? Did you try `c = sListFilePath & Name`?

Answer (score 1):

Try, please changing:

```
 c = Chr(34) & sListFilePath & Name & Chr(34)
```

with

```
 c = sListFilePath & "\" & Name 'if sListFilePath does not include ending "\"
```

or

```
c = sListFilePath & Name ' if ending "\" exists
```

Comment: Yep it is working now :)Thanks a ton for the help